# Problems with pylab errorbar and pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm getting a very confusing error message when I try to use pandas and pylab.errorbar together.

I have a data frame named summary:

```
   year  treatment        SE      mean test
0  2012    Control  0.452069  0.904387    A
1  2012  Pesticide  0.246149  1.365210    B
2  2013    Control  1.073697  3.649746    A
3  2013  Pesticide  1.234574  2.593122    B
```

When I try to make an errorbar plot:

```
for n in summary['treatment'].unique():
    py.errorbar(summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['year'], 
                summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['mean'], 
                summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['SE'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-171-12bf2023b562>", line 2, in <module>
    py.errorbar(summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['year'], summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['mean'], summary[summary['treatment'] == n]['SE'])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2697, in errorbar
    errorevery=errorevery, capthick=capthick, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5749, in errorbar
    iterable(yerr[0]) and iterable(yerr[1])):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 618, in __getitem__
    return self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 724, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
  File "index.pyx", line 96, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2873)
  File "index.pyx", line 104, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2685)
  File "index.pyx", line 148, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3422)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 382, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6570)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 388, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6511)
KeyError: 0
```

I've tried to sort this out. I can plot this:

```
py.errorbar(summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Control']['year'],
            summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Control']['mean'],
            yerr = summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Control']['SE'], fmt = 'o')
```

and this:

```
py.errorbar(summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['year'],
            summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['mean'],
            yerr = summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Control']['SE'], fmt = 'o')
```

but not this:

```
py.errorbar(summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['year'],
            summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['mean'],
            yerr = summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['SE'], fmt = 'o')
```

So there's something about the 'Pesticide' treatment in the yerr that is causing the problem. I've used a similar loop in the past with success, so there's something specific to this setup. NOTE: I've also used the 'test' column in lieu of the 'treatment' column and get the same error.

Thought on why this is failing here?

Comment: The error looks un-related to mpl.  Does `summary[summary['treatment'] == 'Pesticide']['SE']` work correctly?\

Comment: I've also discovered that if I convert the yerr to an numpy array, as in np.array( summary....['SE'] ) it works fine. I'm just confused as to why I need to do that here when I haven't before.

Comment: did you upgrade to the latest `pandas`?  They changed `series` to not derive from ndarrays recently which breaks all sorts of stuff in mpl.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2775

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using pandas 0.12.0. This code works with another set of data just fine. There's something about this particular set.

Comment: interesting.  I still think this is a `pandas` issue, it might be worth creating an issue on their github page (assuming you can share the data which causes this problem).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Using pandas 0.19.0 .